# outputting selected dummy var coefficients using areg absorb option in stata

Tags: regression, stata

Running a regression of price on rent, flavors available, and dummy vars for firm

```
clear all
set obs 300
gen firm = ""
forvalues i = 1/150{
   replace firm = "firm_`i'" in `i'
}
replace firm = "Ben & Jerry's" in 151/200
replace firm = "Cold Stone" in 201/250
replace firm = "Rita's" in 251/300
gen rent = rnormal(1000,50)
gen flavors_avail = rnormal(30,10)
gen price = rnormal(5,1.5)

areg price rent flavors_avail, absorb(firm)
```

How can I output coefficients and significance for the dummy vars representing the Big 3 firms (Ben & Jerry's, Cold Stone and Rita's) but suppress output for the 150 independents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `regress` (which will show them all, but quietly will suppress that), but then use `margins` to show only the ones you want:

```
capture ssc install sencode 
capture ssc install esttab
sencode firm, replace
gen constant = 1
quietly reg price rent flavors_avail i.firm constant, nocons
margins, dydx(rent flavors_avail 151.firm 152.firm 153.firm constant)
```

Note that I tricked `margins` into showing the constant so that you have it for the comparison to the 3 big chains.

You could also do something like this with `esttab` from SSC:

```
esttab, keep(rent flavors_avail 151.firm 152.firm 153.firm constant) label
```

Comment: `ssc` installs one package at a time, so I've edited the code slightly.